# RxJs - Subscribe to observable at last place

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a angular 4 app. In this app I have a paypal service, which does some server work and navigates (from client) to paypal.

```js
 
@Injectable()
export class PaypalService {
  private readonly http: HttpApi;

  constructor(private readonly httpFactory: HttpFactoryService) { 
    this.http = httpFactory.get(HttpRequestType.Secured);
  }

  checkout(transactionId: string):
   Observable<Response> {
    let subscriber = this.http.post(environment.paymentServer + '/pay', {transactionId: transactionId})
    subscriber.subscribe((response:Response) => {
        let result = response.json();
        window.location.href = result.paymentUrl;
    });
    return subscriber;
  }
}
```

I want the window.location.href will be called only after all subscribers was notified.

```js
paypal.checkout("1234").subscribe(() =>
//This code should be called before the navigation will start
doSomeCleaning())
```

I know I can use delay, but I was wondering if there is a better option.

Comment: Try to map all streams with `flatMap` operator for example and at end to have only one subscribe method from which you can call the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to force the observers to be called in specific order you shouldn't rely on their order of subscriptions. The easiest way is to use `setTimeout()` without any delay:

```
observable.subscribe((response:Response) => {
    let result = response.json();
    setTimeout(() => window.location.href = result.paymentUrl);
});
```

Or maybe a better and more Rx way could be using `observeOn` operator and the `async` Scheduler to emit the value to the first observer in another JS event.

```
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';

...

let observable = ...
observable.observeOn(async).subscribe(...);

return observable;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please allaborate little more about the async solution?

Comment: What you want to know?

Comment: What observable.observeOn(async) will do?

Comment: It runs every emission in a separate JS even. Just like you used `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do redirect in callback as following:

```
paypal.checkout("1234").subscribe((res) =>{
   doSomeCleaning();
   window.location.href = res.paymentUrl; 
});
```

Comment: I don't want other component to know about the navigation to paypal